# iteratively recalculating value of a column in pandas based on row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
               'date':['2017-03-27','2017-04-03','2017-04-10','2017-04-17','2017-04-24','2017-05-01', '2017-03-27','2017-04-03','2017-04-10','2017-04-17','2017-04-24','2017-05-01'],
               'sls':[3,4,5,3,2,3,5,6,10,4,5,2],
               'prc':[0,2,0,1,1,7,2,4,0,1,1,1],
               'stk':[7,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

which looks like:

`item        date  sls  prc  stk
0      1  2017-03-27    3    0    7
1      1  2017-04-03    4    2    0
2      1  2017-04-10    5    0    0
3      1  2017-04-17    3    1    0
4      1  2017-04-24    2    1    0
5      1  2017-05-01    3    7    0
6      2  2017-03-27    5    2   12
7      2  2017-04-03    6    4    0
8      2  2017-04-10   10    0    0
9      2  2017-04-17    4    1    0
10     2  2017-04-24    5    1    0
11     2  2017-05-01    2    1    0`

I wanted to calculate the values of column `stk` except of the first record of each `item` group.

I created another column stock with the calculated values:

```
def f(g):
g.stk = (g.stk.shift() + g.prc - g.sls).cumsum()
return g

df['stock'] = df.stk.replace(0, df.groupby('item').apply(f).stk)
```

so my updated dataframe became:

`item        date  sls  prc  stk  stock
0      1  2017-03-27    3    0    7      7
1      1  2017-04-03    4    2    0      5
2      1  2017-04-10    5    0    0      0
3      1  2017-04-17    3    1    0     -2
4      1  2017-04-24    2    1    0     -3
5      1  2017-05-01    3    7    0      1
6      2  2017-03-27    5    2   12     12
7      2  2017-04-03    6    4    0     10
8      2  2017-04-10   10    0    0      0
9      2  2017-04-17    4    1    0     -3
10     2  2017-04-24    5    1    0     -7
11     2  2017-05-01    2    1    0     -8`

But I don't want the negative value in the `stock` column. So how can I make the iterative calculation that if for a `item` group if there is a negative value in a record in the `stock` column, it must add that number to the value in the first record and again do the computation. till there are no more negative values.

The `stock` column in calculated as value at(stk-1) - value at sls + value at prc

My expected output looks like:

`item        date  sls  prc  stk  stock
0      1  2017-03-27    3    0    7     10
1      1  2017-04-03    4    2    0      8
2      1  2017-04-10    5    0    0      3
3      1  2017-04-17    3    1    0      1
4      1  2017-04-24    2    1    0      0
5      1  2017-05-01    3    7    0      4
6      2  2017-03-27    5    2   12     20
7      2  2017-04-03    6    4    0     18
8      2  2017-04-10   10    0    0      8
9      2  2017-04-17    4    1    0      5
10     2  2017-04-24    5    1    0      1
11     2  2017-05-01    2    1    0      0`

How can I do the same in pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution:

```
df['stock'] -= (df.groupby('item').stock
                  .transform(lambda x: x.min() if x.min()<0 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do as is and then add your minimum negative value to the column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
               'date':['2017-03-27','2017-04-03','2017-04-10','2017-04-17','2017-04-24','2017-05-01', '2017-03-27','2017-04-03','2017-04-10','2017-04-17','2017-04-24','2017-05-01'],
               'sls':[3,4,5,3,2,3,5,6,10,4,5,2],
               'prc':[0,2,0,1,1,7,2,4,0,1,1,1],
               'stk':[7,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0]})

def f(g):
    g.stk = (g.stk.shift() + g.prc - g.sls).cumsum()
    return g

df['stock'] = df.stk.replace(0, df.groupby('item').apply(f).stk)
df['stock'] = df.groupby('item')['stock'].apply(lambda x: x - x.min() if x.min() < 0 else 0)
```

Comment: can you try running the solution, the value for first group are coming wrong

Comment: I am sorry, forgot about groupby

df['stock'] = df.groupby('item')['stock'].apply(lambda x: x - x.min() if x.min() < 0 else 0)